# RCPP generated DLL files triggering Bit9 errors

Tags: r, security, dll, rcpp

I am attempting to use the Rcpp package and RStudio to build C++ functions. My main roadblock is dealing with my agency's Bit9 system. Each time I attempt to compile, the resulting DLL file (I am running Windows) triggers a Bit9 error. In order to prevent a DLL file from triggering a Bit9 error, I need to provide my IT department with the names of all the DLL files I want to use (I cannot even install packages). I have noticed that Rcpp generates DLLs with incremental file names (e.g., `sourcecpp_1.dll`, `sourcecpp_3.dll`). Has anyone encountered this issue before?  If so, how did you deal with it?

Comment: I would suggest to work on a non-castrated computer.

Comment: Tell me about it!  These restrictions are in place because my agency deals with sensitive data (health records).  Is there a way to specify the name of the outputted dll file?  If so, I could give that name to my IT department and reuse it.

Comment: You would have to tweak R's (internal) wrappers around `make`. But it should not be numbered as you see: one object file per source file, and then one library / dll with the same name as the package.

Comment: I am working off of Hadley's introductory examples using the cppFunction [link](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html).  Each time I run it, it creates a new incrementally named dll file in a new folder in AppData\Local\Temp.  My IT department just approved dll files starting with  sourcecpp and I was able to get the examples to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an Bit9 employee so what I tell you is the truth.

The Bit9 admin, using the event stream in the Bit9 console, can see what process is writing those DLLs to disk and mark that process as an installer. What that means is that process is promoted such that any "interesting" files (exe, dll, driver file, system file, script) it writes to disk will be approved. They can be specific enough that it is limited to a particular directory and it's subdirectories.

If your Bit9 administrator doesn't know how to write such a rule, or is concerned about the security implications  of such a rule have them go to the Bit9 ( we've changed our name to Carbon Black) [User Exchange](http://HTTPS://community.carbonblack.com) and they can get additional feedback.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information, BJ!  I will definitely pass it on to my IT department.